# How to get the equation of a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation of a line is of the form:

\begin{align*}
Ax + By + C = 0
\end{align*}

My question is, how has this equation been obtained? Why, for example, does the term $A$ multiply $x$, instead of dividing it or simply not being? Why does this equation describe all those points and what is the proof that this is true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it $$Ax+By+C=0$$?

Comment: Yes Sonnhard, i already edited the question. My question is how to get from geometric graph ( in this case a line ) to a algebraic representation

Comment: A line has i) a starting point ii) a constant slope $m$ which represents how much the line rises in relation to how much it "runs".  If the starting point is $(0, b)$ then you get the equation $y = mx + b$.  If we multiply this by any non negative $B$ we get $-mBx + By - bB = 0$.  Replace $-mB$ with $A$ and $-bB$ with C and you get $Ax + By + C = 0$.  Why $B$?  Why not B?  It possible a line can be straight up and down.  This allow for $B=0$ and the line is just $x = d = -\frac CA$.  Why $A$? Same reason if the line is flat $y = b= -\frac CB$ and $A = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The general form $Ax+By+C=0$ is being used to describe all possible lines in $2D$. Why do we multiply by $A$? Because we cannot divide by zero. Multiplication avoids such issues and allows us to describe lines such as $x=3$ or $y=-1$. Why the graph of all solutions to a linear equation is a line? Think that line has always the same slope at any point and this slope is defined by an angle between the line and axis $X$. That angle can be described by a tangent which is equal to the ratio of change in $y$ to change in $x$. If you have two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ which are solutions of $Ax+By+C=0$ then we have $Ax_1+By_1+C=0$ and $Ax_2+By_2+C=0$. The tangent ratio (slope) will be $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{C-Ax_2-C+Ax_1}{B(x_2-x_1)}=-\frac{A}{B}$. As you can see, the slope does not depend on $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ which means it will be the same for any pair of points.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a line is obtained from a direction and a point. Without loss of generality, let us assume that $\textbf{d} = (d_{1},d_{2})$ is the direction where $d_{1}d_{2}\neq 0$ and $\textbf{P} = (p_{1},p_{2})$ is some point of it. Thus the points $(x,y)$ of the line passing through $\textbf{P}$ along the direction $\textbf{d}$ must satisfy:
\begin{align*}
& (x,y) = \lambda\textbf{d} + \textbf{P} = \lambda(d_{1},d_{2}) + (p_{1},p_{2}) = (\lambda d_{1} + p_{1},\lambda d_{2} + p_{2}) \Longleftrightarrow\\\\
&\begin{cases}
x = \lambda d_{1} + p_{1}\\
y = \lambda d_{2} + p_{2}
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow \lambda = \frac{x-p_{1}}{d_{1}} = \frac{y - p_{2}}{d_{2}} \Longleftrightarrow d_{2}x - d_{1}y - p_{1}d_{2} + d_{1}p_{2} = 0 \\\\
&\therefore Ax + By + C = 0\,\,\text{where}\,\,A = d_{2},\, B = -d_{1}\,\,\text{and}\,\,C = -p_{1}d_{2} + d_{1}p_{2}
\end{align*}

If $d_{1} = 0$, you obtain a vertical line. If $d_{2} = 0$, you obtain a horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

"how has this equation been obtained?"

$y = mx + b \iff -mx + y - b = 0 \iff -mkx + ky - bk = 0; k \ne 0 \iff Ax + By + C=0; A=-mk; B=k; C =-bk; k\ne 0$.

....

$Ax + By + C = 0$ doesn't "mean" anything.

It's just that:

Case 1:  $B \ne 0$.

$Ax + By + C = 0 \iff$

$By = -Ax - C \iff$

$y = -\frac ABx -\frac CB \iff$

$y = mx + b; m = -\frac AB; b = -\frac CB$.

Now the equation $y = mx + b$ for a line *DOES* mean something.

$m$ is the slope (rise/run) of a line.  By the geometric nature of a line (as opposed to a curve) we know this always exists and is constant.  And $b$ is the $y$ value where the line crosses the $y$-axis.  (This always occurs unless the line is straight up and down vertical.)

Case 2:  $B = 0; A\ne 0$.

Then $Ax + By + C = 0\implies Ax = -C \implies x = -\frac CA$.

If we set $d = -\frac CA$ then this is a straigh up and down vertical line where $x = d$.

That's all.

Case 3:  $A=0; b=0$

The this is just a statement $C = 0$.  It's not the eqaution of a line.  It's just a statement that there is a constant $C = 0$.

....

So $Ax + By + C = 0$ will always be a line (unless $A = B = 0$).  Not because $A,B,C$ mean anything but because they can be manipulated into something that does.

===== old answer below... which explains why $y = mx + b$ is the equation of a line ====

A point of a line is $(c,d)$  and if you travel along the $x$ axis some distance of $t$ then you must travel up the $y$ axis for some proportional distance of $m*t$ where $m$ is the slope of this particular line.

So you end up at the point $(c + t, d + m*t)$.

Now $t$ can be any distance.  So for any variable of $t$ distance you have $(x,y) = (c + t, d+m*t)$ with $x = c+t$ and $y = d + m*t$.

If we express this in terms of $x$ (rather than in terms of $t$ we get)

$x = c + t$ so $t = x - c$ so $y = d + m *t = d + m(x - c) = mx + (c-md)$.

So the equation of a line is $y = mx + (c-md)$.

This is interpreted as $m =$ the slope of the line.  And $c$ can be the $x$ coordinate of *any* point on the line and $d$ is the *coresponding* $y$ coordinate.

If we plug in $x=0$ we get $y = c-md = b$ and this is the $y$-intercept of the line (the $y$ coordinate when the line crosses the $y$-axis.)

This gives us the more common equation of the line $y = mx + b$.

We can convert this to your form by multiplying both sides by *any* non-zero $B$.  Then we get: $By = mBx + bB$

$-mBx + By -bB = 0$.

$Ax + By + C = 0$ where $A = -mB$ and $C = -bB$

The numbers $A, B, $ and $C$ have no meaning or significance by the do have a relationship that $-\frac AB = m$ the slope of the line.  And $-\frac CB$ is the $y$ intercept of the line and $-\frac CA$ is the $x$ intercept of the line.

In other words:

If you have an equation $Ax + By + C = 0$ you know it is a line.

You know that if you plug in $x=0$ you get $y = -\frac CB = b$ is the $y$-intercept. And you know that $y = -\frac ABx - \frac CB$ so that for every unit of $1$ that $x$ changes then $y$ will change by $-\frac AB$ so the $-\frac AB = m$ is the slope of the line.